# Unable to scrape multiple pages using scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a project to scrape data from class-central.com. If you open this website and click on any one of the subjects (for eg. Computer Science), you will get a list of courses. At the bottom of the page, there is a next button that displays more courses and this continues till all courses have been displayed. I want to scrape all the courses.

```
    import scrapy
    from ..items import ClasscentralItem
    class ClassCentral(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spidy'
    start_urls = [
      'https://www.classcentral.com/subject/cs'
  ]
    def parse(self, response):
    items = ClasscentralItem()
    all_tr = response.css('#course-listing-tbody tr[itemscope]')
    courses = response.css('.number-of-courses .text--bold::text')
    for x in all_tr:
        sub = response.css('.medium-up-head-1::text').extract()
        course_name = x.css('.course-name .text--bold::text').get()
        course_devloper = x.css('.uni-name::text').extract()
        via = x.css('.text--italic::text').get()
        duration = x.css('.icon-clock-charcoal::text').extract()
        start_date = x.css('.medium-only-hidden::text').get()
        rating = x.css('td:nth-child(4)').attrib['data-timestamp']
        number_review = x.css('td#span#a::text').get()
        items['subjectname'] = sub
        items['course_name'] = course_name
        items['course_devloper'] = course_devloper
        items['via'] = via
        items['duration'] = duration
        items['start_date'] = start_date
        items['rating'] = rating
        items['number_review'] = number_review
        yield items
```

I am struggling with **scraping the courses that are displayed after clicking on the 'Next' button.**
Also, I am **unable to scrape the 'Number of Revies' on each course**.
Here is my code,

Please help.

(PS: I am a beginner so please try to make your answer as simple as possible)

Comment: Use this link `https://www.classcentral.com/maestro/subject/cs?page=1` to get the content from that site. All you need to do is change the page number to get the content from next pages.

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html